# Why the List does not appear?

Tags: swiftui

Why the `presetsList` does not appear? No errors were thrown though.

```
import SwiftUI
 
struct AddMessagePreset: View {
    let presetsList = [
        Preset(name: "preset text 1"),
        Preset(name: "preset text 2"),
        Preset(name: "preset text 3")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        
        List(presetsList) { singlePresetModel in
                 SinglePresetChild (presetModel: singlePresetModel)
         }
    }
}



import SwiftUI

struct Preset: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct SinglePresetChild: View {
    
    var presetModel: Preset
    
    var body: some View {
         
            Text("Preset Name \(presetModel.name)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code works well for me using macos 12.2 Beta, Xcode 13.2, 
targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Tested on real devices. It may be different on older systems.

Comment: I also tested it on Xcode 13.2.1 and it works fine. The issue might be in how you are using your main component `AddMessagePreset`. Please add some more code showing how you use it in your app or your preview.

Comment: @dr_barto I use the component as follows. `var body: some View {   
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                
                AddMessagePreset ()
}}}`

Comment: there are other components in the VStack, they are visible, but this `AddMessagePreset` simply doesn't appear. If I place something in it (such as image or text') then that component appears in the `AddMessagePreset` component, just the list is not visible. May be I need to use `for each` etc to make the list appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: To show a `List` inside another `ScrollView` (or `List`), you have to set a height on the inner list view:

```swift
struct Preview: View {
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      AddMessagePreset().frame(height: 200)
      // more views ...
    }
  }
}
```

But let me advise against doing so. Having nested scroll areas can be very confusing for the user.

---

As discussed in the comments, your component code is fine. However, the way you integrate it into your app causes a problem. Apparently, nesting a `List` inside a `ScrollView` does not work properly (also see [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126898)).

`List` is already scrollable vertically, so you won't need the additional `ScrollView`:

```swift
struct Preview: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      AddMessagePreset()
    }
  }
}
```

P.S.: If you only want to show `AddMessagePreset` and won't add another sibling view, you can remove the wrapping `VStack`; or even show `AddMessagePreset` as the main view, without any wrapper.

Comment: `List is already scrollable vertically, so you won't need the additional ScrollView` `Yes I do need a scrollable list inside a `Scrollview``, because The list is the top part of the scroll-able page, the page has many other components, which goes below that scroll view. user is selecting something from 'List' and it will be used in a component just below the list, let's say user is clicking an item in the list and the text of the selected item is displayed under that scrollable list. Use cases are to the infinity.